# Disable Hindi language for Google interfaces in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Chrome 21, and realized that lately all of the Google web applications such as Google Maps, Google Analytics, Google Reader, etc. are coming up in Hindi.

I am from India and Hindi is the main language here. I have heard that Google recently implemented this feature that detects the location of the user (I'm not sure whether they're using IP address or HTML5 geolocation), and automatically presents the content in the local language.

I want to disable this.

My Chrome settings already contain English as the default language and Location Auto detect is disabled. Still it does not work.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: On your computer, go to the Search settings page.(https://www.google.com/preferences)
On the left, click Languages.
Choose your language settings.
Which language should Google products use: This setting changes the language for the Google interface, including messages and buttons on your screen.
Currently showing search results in: This setting lets you pick more languages to see search results in. We try to automatically find results written in the language you selected above, but you can always choose more languages.
At the bottom of the page, click Save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not to do with Chrome, it's Google's detection of your IP address.

I would recommend creating a Google account and then setting your preferences in there. This means whenever you log onto to any PC, all you need to do is log onto your account and your preferences should be as you want.

Try this: http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35892

General details:

1) Go to the Google search homepage, www.google.com.

2) Click on the Advanced Search link beside the search box. Specify the language of your choice in the Language section. This is recommended if it is a one off search in that language. If you need to make the language selection permanent, follow steps 3 and 4 below.

3) Click on the Preferences link beside the search box. Select from the list of languages given in the 'Search Language' section and save the preferences. This is recommended if you frequently search for pages in a particular language.

4) Set Google to display its tips and messages in any language. This can be done by clicking on the Preferences link and selecting an Interface Language from the drop down menu.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Chrome.
2. Click on three dots on top right. Click on 'Settings' in drop down.
3. Click on Languages.
4. Remove Hindi. Also disable 'Offer to translate pages in other languages'.
   The irritating translations will cease.

Comment: This worked as of Mar 19, 2020. The issue was not with Google websites though. Random websites started translating numbers to Hindi (Devanagri).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue when Google search suggestions were coming in Hindi. Since I am a techie guy and most of my searches are related to technical stuffs, showing suggestions and results in Hindi won't help me. Therefore, I followed these steps to make it work in English-

1. Click on three dots located in upper right corner of the browser.
2. Select **Settings**.
3. Following screen should appear-
   [Chrome Setting screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZVhQ.png)
   Select "**Manage search engines**"
4. Under "**Default Search Engines**" heading, Google would have been set as default.
5. You should see other search engines as well. Make some other search engine as default. Let's say Yahoo. Click on three dots beside Yahoo and select "**Make Default**".
6. Now click on three dots beside Google search engine and select "**Remove from list**".
7. Restart the browser and search from the address bar. The search results should be generated by Yahoo.
8. Hit **www.google.co.in** from the address bar. Google home page appears.
9. Select **English** from the menu present below Google search bar.
10. Search anything and view the search result.
11. Follow steps 1,2 and 3.You should be able to see the Google.co.in under "**Other search engines**".
12. Click on three dots beside Google.co.in search engine and select "**Make default**". This will promote from "**Other search engines**" to "**Default search engines**".
13. Restart the browser.
14. Search from the address bar and you should see only english suggestions.

    Note: Please upvote the answer if it helps or comment if you face any issue.